# Documentation for mbunit v3

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mbunit, gallio

Any pointers for the documentation on the new features of mbunit v3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [**Wiki**](http://gallio.org/wiki/) and the [**API documentation**](http://gallio.org/api/index.aspx) are the most reliable sources of information for [Gallio](http://gallio.org) and [MbUnit](http://mbunit.com). Some blogs are interesting to read as well (mostly maintained by contributors):

- http://blog.bits-in-motion.com/
- http://interfacingreality.blogspot.com/
- http://weblogs.asp.net/astopford
- http://vkreynin.wordpress.com/

The Wiki is certainly more convenient to read but is still a little sparse. However, the Gallio team members put a lot of efforts in it. They add new articles on almost a daily basis. If some people are volunteer to help, they are welcome to drop a line [here](http://groups.google.com/group/gallio-dev?lnk=li).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the references.

Comment: Gallio and MbUnit are on hiatus as of Jan. 2015, and the API docs have been pulled. You can still find (bits and pieces of) the docs on the Wayback Machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20130223063637/http://www.gallio.org/api/index.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The release notes are located [here](http://blog.bits-in-motion.com/search/label/release%20notes) and the main documentation site is [here](http://www.gallio.org/Docs.aspx). Didn't they show up when you Googled it?

Comment: Thanks for the link of release notes. 

The documentation site is not updated and most of the content pages are blank.

Comment: The contents of the wiki and the API doc are up-to-date, but incomplete unfortunately. It was only put in place a few weeks ago. We focus on filling it with good articles and useful examples. Unfortunately, we lack of manpower. In fact, we would need more people to help us and make Gallio grow.

Answer (score 0):

There's a Release Candidate for MbUnit 3.2.  You can read about new features [here](http://gallio.org/wiki/doku.php?id=release_notes:v3.2).